# Creating a table that shows a function evaluated for sequences

Tags: r, for-loop

How would I create a table that takes two varaibles composed of incremental sequences and evaluates a function for the these two variables. An example of what I want to create is like a multiplication table. So the function would be x*y and it would produce a table where [row, column] [1,1]=1, [1,2]=2 [5,5]=25 etc
I think you can use for loops bit I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

JOE this is pretty basic ... try to follow a basic data manipulation tutorial.
For this type of operations you do not need loops. Read up on vector operations.
What you want to do can be easily done in R with a data frame/tibble.

**base R**

```
# create your test vectors
x <- c(1,1,5)
y <- c(1,2,5)
# store them in a data frame
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
df
  x y
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 5 5

# in base R you code by refernce to the object and dollar notation
df$mult <- df$x * df$y
df
  x y mult
1 1 1    1
2 1 2    2
3 5 5   25
```

**tidyverse**
The tidyverse might be a bit more intuitive for vectorised operations:

```
library(dplyr) # the main data crunching package of the tidyverse
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
# with mutate you can create a new vector (or overwrite an existing one)
df <- df %>% mutate(MULT = x * y)
df
  x y MULT
1 1 1    1
2 1 2    2
```

Good luck with your learning journey!
3 5 5   25